# How do I allow ipv6 traffic for my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I cannot access WordPress website thru ipv6 proxy. Can I configure a WordPress website to allow ipv6 traffic? I know I have to specify `::` as host, but where?

I'm also not sure which tags should I use for this post...

Comment: Are you hosting this yourself, or is it hosted on wordpress.com ? (as you've tagged)

Comment: But from WordPress's point of view it shouldn't really matter. If your site is example.com, and you access it via an IPv6 AAAA record that resolved example.com into an IPv6 address that your server responds to, I'd think everything would just work.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 localhost address but I don't think you'd use that anywhere for routing to a public site.

Comment: Actually can I check which way around the proxy is? Are you connecting to the proxy as IPv6, then the proxy connects to your site over IPv4, or are you using a proxy to make a test IPv6 connection to your site i.e. you want the site to handle IPv6 itself?

Comment: It is hosted by WordPress.com. the WordPress website doesn't accept ipv6 connections. Chatgpt says I cannot permit it manually and that I need to contact WordPress support. I want my site to handle ipv6.

Comment: Yes we can't help with wordpress.com support here - you'll have to talk to them. [The latest IPv6 thread in their support forum](https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/ipv6-support-missing/) asks why it's needed, but doesn't add anything useful. And there's a [trac ticket for api.wordpress.org IPv6](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3090) that says it's not supported by their host, but I don't know how much the wp.org and wp.com hosting have in common. However I'd guess you're out of luck and this isn't something they can just enable for you.